# DSpace error with oai import

Tags: solr, dspace, oai

After configuring my DSpace server, its working correctly but when I look at the OAI identify page (http://repositorio.puce.edu.ec/oai/request?verb=Identify) so we can be harvested, it says that the repository is localhost instead of my URL. I investigated and found out that to update this, I have to run this command: *dspace*/bin/dspace oai import -c but when I run that command is gives me the following error: Solr server (http://repositorio.puce.edu.ec/solr/oai) is down, turn it on.

I can see the Solr Admin (it can't be seen from the outside because of security reasons) so I don't know what should be turned on or how to do it?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered this error in the past.

Looking at my oai.cfg file, I used localhost for some settings and my public URL for others.

```
solr.url=http://localhost/solr/oai
# OAI persistent identifier prefix.
# Format - oai:PREFIX:HANDLE
identifier.prefix = repository.library.georgetown.edu
# Base url for bitstreams
bitstream.baseUrl = https://repository.library.georgetown.edu
```

If you need to make a config change, be sure to clear the cache after restarting service.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it right now. Do you mean clearing Tomcat's cache? (that's the server I'm using) Or does DSpace store some kind of cache independently?

Comment: There is a cache for the OAI service.  ".../bin/dspace oai clean-cache" will clear it.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it with dspace oai clean-cache. My oai.cfg file looks just like yours but still giving me the same message about turning on Solr when trying to import.

Comment: Could you post an error message from your dspace/solr/tomcat logs that might have more information?

Comment: I just checked those logs and couldn't find any useful information about this issue. 
These are the tomcat logs: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/crvalencia/ekMgd
These are the dspace logs: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/crvalencia/G4nGA
https://bitbucket.org/snippets/crvalencia/A4nA6

Comment: I agree.  I do not see anything useful there either.  Since you can see the oai solr repo but not the oai service, I have a question. If you look at your tomcat/webapps configuration, is the oai service configured there?

Comment: Using the clear-cache command actually fixed the identifier issue if you check http://repositorio.puce.edu.ec/oai/request?verb=Identify but the import command is still not working. The oai webapp is copied to the tomcat/webapps folder if that is what you were asking

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79366/discussion-between-terrywb-and-christian).

Comment: the import issue was caused by the solr server not being included in the port configuration of the dspace server, so it remained in port 8080. I changed the value for solr.url=http://localhost/solr/oai to solr.url=http://localhost:8080/solr/oai and it worked!. Thank you so much for your patience and help!